# Permissions with sidekiq monit and capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq, capistrano3, sidekiq-monitor

I'm having troubles with capistrano and sidekiq monit.

I setup a user for capistrano and everything was going smoothly until I installed Sidekiq.

My problem is when I try to execute `cap staging sidekiq:monit:config` (`sidekiq:monit:start` has the same permission problem).
Everytime I've tried, it "freezes" because it asks for the password.

Then I tryed to set `sidekiq_monit_use_sudo` to false. It's ok, it doesn't use sudo, but then it doesn't have permission to copy the `/tmp/monit.conf` into `/etc/monit/conf.d/` folder.

It's the first time I'm setting up a server and I'm kinda lost here =|
Maybe try to config the sidekiq monit manually?

I'm using ruby 2.5 and these gems:

- capistrano 3.10
- capistrano-sidekiq 1.0
- rails 5.1

Also I have the `:pty` config set to `true` as I don't feel comfortable not using a password.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options, of which I'll define two, the right one, and the easy/bad one.

### Local User Monit

My personal usage of Monit is on a shared server on which I do not have root access. So I run Monit itself as a non-root user.

In order to do this, I compiled Monit with its prefix as `$HOME/apps`, so that the config files are in `$HOME/apps/etc`. This avoids the sudo issue. If you have access to the package manager and installed Monit that way, you can run monit as your user with the `-c` param to define where it should look for configuration files:

```
monit -c $HOME/config/monitrc
```

In order to get Capistrano to recognize the local monit, you will need some extra parameters in `config/deploy.rb`:

```
#set :monit_bin, '/usr/bin/monit' # Use this if you compile monit yourself.
set :sidekiq_monit_conf_dir, '/home/myuser/config/monit.d' # Feel free to customize.
set :sidekiq_monit_use_sudo, false
```

In the monitrc file you have defined with the `-c` option, you will need to make sure whatever folder you define in `:sidekiq_monit_conf_dir` is pulled in via includes:

```
include /home/myuser/config/monit.d/*.conf
```

Since I don't have an init system, I have Cron start Monit every 30 minutes, which is a noop if it is already running:

```
# Restart monit if it dies
*/30 * * * * $HOME/apps/bin/monit > /dev/null
```

If you have root access, you can improve upon this by having an init script (or [systemd unit file](https://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/Systemd)) start Monit as your local user.

### Bad option: give your user access to the conf dir

You can edit `/etc/monit/monitrc` to include your local user config directory as above. Similarly, you can allow your user to write to `/etc/monit/conf.d`. The major downside of these solutions is that you are now allowing your non-root user to create files which will be executes as root, opening a privilege escalation vulnerability. If your user ever got compromised, you certainly don't want an easy way for the attacker to get to root.

I include this option mostly because it's commonly considered, and should be avoided in the vast majority of cases (such as whenever you care about security). However, this might be useful in occasional rare cases (such as when you have a short term server for internal use only behind a firewall with only trusted users, and you need to set it up in a hurry).